# How do I edit /etc/sudoers from a script?

Tags: linux, shell, sudo

I need to edit `/etc/sudoers` from a script to add/remove stuff from white lists.

Assuming I have a command that would work on a normal file, how could I apply it to `/etc/sudoers`?

Can I copy and modify it, then have `visudo` replace the original with the modified copy? By providing my own script in `$EDITOR`?

Or can I just use the same locks and `cp`?

The question is more about potential issues than about just finding something that works.

Answer (score 196):

Old thread, but what about:

```
echo 'foobar ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL' | sudo EDITOR='tee -a' visudo
```

Comment: This is a great answer.  The whole subshell should be executed as root, e.g. `echo "$USER ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/rsync" | (sudo su -c 'EDITOR="tee" visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/rsync')`.

Comment: This answer works great! I use it for postinst skripts in debian packages. thanks! Since this is always root, it gets short and handy: `echo "$CONFIGLINE" | (EDITOR="tee -a" visudo)`

Comment: I just want to point out a major nuance to @BorisDäppen's answer: the `-a` flag to `EDITOR="tee"`: it will append line to the file, not only overwrite the first line. I didn't catch the different at first and I couldn't figure the way to append. I hope I can find some people some time by pointing that directly ;-)

Comment: `EDITOR` enviroment variable is only set for visudo, no need for a subshell. It does NOT affect the calling shell.

Comment: Your change broke it for me.

Comment: echo 'includedir /etc/sudoers.d' | EDITOR='tee -a' sudo visudo
visudo: no editor found (editor path = /usr/bin/editor)

Comment: @DanielP Try the update. I'm fairly certain the environment varialbe `EDITOR` was supposed to be on the right hand side of sudo.

Comment: can someone explain me how this work i mean isn't the semicolon required after EDITOR='tee -a'. I know that will break the command. EDITOR is a shell variable and visudo is yet another command so here we are passing EDITOR and visudo in same command line. how does that really works ?

Comment: @Sagar:  the construct    :  `var=value   command arguments` : launches "command arguments" but also set in its environnement the variable "var" to "value" (temporarily, just during command's execution, without actually setting var=value in the surrounding shell!). so there they start a visudo, but set its environnement "EDITOR" to "tee -a" so that this visudo uses tee -a instead of vi. At the end of this command, EDITOR is still at its former value in the shell, it never changed there (just was set in "visudo" environnement, during the time of visudo's execution)

Comment: I tried this x="something" echo $x. This did't work for me.

Comment: @Sagar I think that's because `$x` gets expanded before it is passed to `echo`, but only inside the execution of `echo` is `x` set to `something`. Try instead: `x="something" python -c "import os; print(os.environ['x'])"`.

Comment: wow that worked for me @nog642. Apparently both echo and python are binary commands, I also gave a try with printf and assured its not bash built in command. I tested the same scenario with awk as well. `echo dummy | x='something' awk -v a=$x 'BEGIN{print a}'`

Comment: To prevent duplicate records: `if [ -z "$(grep 'foobar ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL' /etc/sudoers )" ]; then echo "foobar ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" | sudo EDITOR='tee -a' visudo; fi;`

Comment: I propose echo 'foobar ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL' | sudo EDITOR='tee -a' visudo --file=/etc/sudoers.d/yoursudoers (it permits to separate your sudoers from the original sudoers file)

Answer (score 46):

Use visudo for this with a custom editor. This solves all the race conditions and "hack" problems with Brian's solution.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  echo "Starting up visudo with this script as first parameter"
  export EDITOR=$0 && sudo -E visudo
else
  echo "Changing sudoers"
  echo "# Dummy change to sudoers" >> $1
fi
```

This script will add the line "# Dummy change to sudoers" to the end of sudoers. No hacks and no race conditions.

Annotated version that explains how this actually works:

```
if [ -z "$1" ]; then

  # When you run the script, you will run this block since $1 is empty.

  echo "Starting up visudo with this script as first parameter"

  # We first set this script as the EDITOR and then starts visudo.
  # Visudo will now start and use THIS SCRIPT as its editor
  export EDITOR=$0 && sudo -E visudo
else

  # When visudo starts this script, it will provide the name of the sudoers 
  # file as the first parameter and $1 will be non-empty. Because of that, 
  # visudo will run this block.

  echo "Changing sudoers"

  # We change the sudoers file and then exit  
  echo "# Dummy change to sudoers" >> $1
fi
```

Comment: This requires that sudo has been compiled with `--enable-env-editor`, otherwise it will only use respect the editor variable if it is one of a small set of known values.

Comment: It works for me (Ubuntu 12.04), but I don't understand how it works. Could someone explain how to use it properly and how it actually works? Thanks

Comment: Would like to note that this does not appear to work for me on 12.04 precise. I created a bash script, added +x permissions to it, and executed the file with the following output:

visudo: unable to run /tmp/edit_sudoers: Exec format error
visudo: /etc/sudoers.tmp unchanged

Comment: This worked great for me, although I simply logged in as root and removed the `sudo -E` from the first command.

Comment: I really like this answer, but it didn't work for me. I think my sudo wasn't compiled with the necessary flag.

Comment: Hmm not sure whether it was the sudo compilation thing, but this doesn't work for me either on CentOS 7. The script runs, everything **seems** like it has worked (my echo commands for debugging are printed etc.) but the sudoers file doesn't actually change. I also had to add a shebang to the top of my script before the exec error mentioned by @JoseDiaz-Gonzalez would go away.

Answer (score 30):

You should make your edits to a temporary file, then use visudo -c -f sudoers.temp to confirm that the changes are valid and then copy it over the top of /etc/sudoers

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -f "/etc/sudoers.tmp" ]; then
    exit 1
fi
touch /etc/sudoers.tmp
edit_sudoers /tmp/sudoers.new
visudo -c -f /tmp/sudoers.new
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
    cp /tmp/sudoers.new /etc/sudoers
fi
rm /etc/sudoers.tmp
```

Comment: It looks like you're using sudoers.tmp as a lock file, not sure how that confirms changes are valid. Shouldn't we be checking the exit status of visudo to make sure there are no errors?

Comment: /etc/sudoers.tmp is the lockfile checked by visudo in interactive mode. visudo -c -f returns a 1 if there was an error, hence the check of the return code.

Comment: I'm worried about using sudoers.tmp, as it looks like using visudo's internal interface, i.e., a hack. Is it standard, meaning that it is guaranteed to always be sudoers.tmp that gets used as the lock? Or do they have the freedom to change that in future?

Comment: it also produces a race condition, doesn't it?

Comment: need to use lockfile instead of test/touch

Comment: The manpage says it uses /tmp/sudoers.tmp so that is currently the standard. Of course it could change in the future. And yes, you are right there is a race condition.

Answer (score 25):

On most distributions (at least Debian-based, Redhat-based, openSUSE-based, etc.), you can insert a custom script into the `/etc/sudoers.d/` directory, with rights `0440` - For more information see `man sudo` ("Including other files from within sudo") or the same information on the [official site](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html#Including_other_files_from_within_sudoers).

It might help.

Comment: Isn't it commented out though?

Comment: @TomDworzanski: IMHO no. See [man sudoers(5)](http://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudoers.man.html#x4f74686572207370656369616c206368617261637465727320616e6420726573657276656420776f726473) and [other comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/244064/why-are-the-include-and-includedir-directives-in-sudo-prefixed-with-the-pound).

Comment: You're right! Thanks for the links and great answer.

Comment: I use that directory in centos 7 as well

Answer (score 11):

visudo is supposed to be the human interface for editing `/etc/sudoers`.  You can achieve the same by replacing the file directly, but you have to take care yourself about concurrent editing and syntax validation.  Mind the `r--r-----` permissions.

Answer (score 10):

If your `sudo` allows adding entries in `/etc/sudoers.d`, then you can use this answer by @dragon788:

https://superuser.com/a/1027257/26022

Basically you use `visudo` to verify the file before you copy it into `/etc/sudoers.d`, so you can be sure you're not breaking `sudo` for anyone.

```
visudo -c -q -f filename
```

This checks it and returns success (0) if it's valid, so you can use it with `if`, `&&` and other script boolean operations. Once you validate, just copy it into `/etc/sudoers.d` and it should work. Make sure its owned by root and not writable by other.

Answer (score 9):

Lots of answers, been working with sudo for yonks but did not have a need to automate the setup config till now.
I used a mix of some of the answers above, writing my config line to the /etc/sudoers.d include location so i don't have to modify the main sudoers file, then checked that file for syntax , simple example below:

Write your line to a sudoers include file:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "your_user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >> /etc/sudoers.d/99_sudo_include_file'
```

Check that your sudoers include file passed the visudo syntax checks:

```
sudo visudo -cf /etc/sudoers.d/99_sudo_include_file
```

Comment: Just omit the asterisk, that shouldn't be there ^^

Comment: it and returns success (0) -- got it

Answer (score 5):

This is the solution I came up with. It's a quick and dirty solution, but it works...

```
echo "username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" | sudo tee -a /etc/sudoers
```

It pipes the echo output into tee which is running under sudo. Tee then appends the output into the sudoers file.

Comment: Not a proper solution, compared to the visudo which does the sanity checking as well automatically.

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer. very nice.

Answer (score 4):

Set up a custom editor. Basically it will be a script that accepts the filename (in this case /etc/sudoers.tmp), and modify and save that in place. So you could just write out to that file. When you are done, exit the script, and visudo will take care of modifying the actual sudoers file for you.

```
sudo EDITOR=/path/to/my_dummy_editor.sh visudo
```

Comment: Am I correct that all the dummy_editor.sh need contain is something like this? `#!/bin/sh; echo "# my changes to sudoers" >> $1; exit 0` It seems to work for me.

Answer (score 4):

I think the most straight forward solution is to:

Create a script **addsudoers.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

while [ -n "$1" ]; do
    echo "$1    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" >> /etc/sudoers;
    shift # shift all parameters
done
```

and call it with the users you want to add it as:

```
root prompt> ./addsudoers.sh user1 user2
```

For the full explanation see this answer: [Adding users to sudoers through shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784761/adding-users-to-sudoers-through-shell-script?lq=1)

Regards!

Answer (score 2):

Just to add a further option to the answers above, if the race condition is not a major concern, then the following command can be used to avoid manually copying a modified file to `/etc/sudoers`

```
sudo EDITOR="cp /tmp/sudoers.new" visudo
```

This will ensure that the new file is validated and installed correctly with permissions update.

Note that if there is an error in the `/tmp/sudoers.new` file then `visudo` will prompt for user input so it is advisable to check it with `visudo -c -f /tmp/sudoers.new` first.

Answer (score 0):

Try to echo it. You have to run it in a subshell, though. Example:

`sudo sh -c "echo \"group ALL=(user) NOPASSWD: ALL\" >> /etc/sudoers"`

Answer (score 0):

Since this question has much more pv than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65023995/create-sudo-users-from-script), and `sed` is more flexible comparing to `tee`, I'll just leave the link to a "better" solution and my solution here.

Based on [Valery Panov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65024924/5485989), I wrote this

```
echo 's/^#\s*\(%wheel\s*ALL=(ALL)\s*ALL\)/\1/g' | EDITOR='sed -f- -i' visudo
```

to uncomment this line in `/etc/sudoers`

```
# %wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me based off what others posted here. When i used other peoples script it would open visudo for me but would not make the edit. This made the edit i needed to allow all users, including standard users, to install java 7u17 for safari/firefox.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
rm /etc/sudoers.new
cp /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.new
echo "%everyone   ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/installer -pkg /Volumes/Java 7 Update 17/Java 7 Update 17.pkg -target /" >> /etc/sudoers.new
cp /etc/sudoers.new /etc/sudoers
```

This added the %everyone blah blah blah to the bottom of the sudoers file.
I had to run the script like this.

```
sudo sh sudoersedit.sh
```

Good luck :D