# Adding users to sudoers through shell script

Tags: linux, sh, sudo

Is it possible to add users to the sudoers file through a shell script? 
I've been looking around, still can't find anything.

Comment: Would it make more sense to add a single group entry to `/etc/sudoers`, and add users to that group rather than repeatedly updating the `sudoers` file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I edit /etc/sudoers from a script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323957/how-do-i-edit-etc-sudoers-from-a-script)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You could simply `echo` (with elevated privileges, of course) directly to the `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
sudo -i
echo 'nickw444  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
#             ^^
#             tab
```

(note the tab character between the username and the first `ALL`)

Or, for a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Run me with superuser privileges
echo 'nickw444  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
```

Then save to `somefile.sh`, `chmod a+rx` it, and run `sudo ./somefile.sh` from a terminal window.

To add multiple users, change the script to this;

```
#!/bin/bash

while [[ -n $1 ]]; do
    echo "$1    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" >> /etc/sudoers;
    shift # shift all parameters;
done
```

Then, run the script like this (assuming you saved it as `addsudousers.sh`):

```
sudo ./addsudousers.sh bob joe jeff
```

that is, space-separated.

To read the names from a file:

```
nickw444@laptop ~ $ sudo ./addsudousers.sh `cat listofusers.txt`
```

`listofusers.txt` should also be space-separated.

**Edit:** Jappie Kirk [rightly points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784761/adding-users-to-sudoers-through-shell-script/8784846?noredirect=1#comment31192979_8784846) that you can't directly call `sudo echo ... >> /etc/sudoers` because the `>>` redirection is handled by the shell, which has by that point dropped the superuser privileges. However, if you run a script that contains `echo ... >> /etc/sudoers` and the script itself has superuser privileges, everything should work just fine.

Comment: alternatively, use tee like so: `echo "$MY_USER  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" | sudo tee --append /etc/sudoers`

Comment: This worked to recover a machine with a dead OpenSSH server on GCP/GCE, using the serial console. Only catch is there had to be an account with password to begin with.

Comment: Could we have a check mechanism for if the user is already added

Comment: This should check if the user has already been added.

    if ! grep -qF "$MY_USER  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" /etc/sudoers; then
      # Append the entry to the sudoers file
      echo "$MY_USER  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" | sudo tee --append /etc/sudoers
      if grep -qF "$MY_USER  ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL" /etc/sudoers; then
        echo "Sudoers entry added successfully."
      fi
    else
      echo "Sudoers entry already exists. No changes made."
    fi

Answer (score 11):

No, a straight echo won't work, you have to run it in a subshell. Try this instead:

`sudo sh -c "echo \"group ALL=(user) NOPASSWD: ALL\" >> /etc/sudoers"`

Comment: that's it, The 0440 permission of the sudoers file prevent to do that

Answer (score 6):

There is also the `sudo` group, and you could add users to it (for common configurations of `/etc/sudoers`)

> adduser [username] sudo

Answer (score 2):

on **RedHat Based** Distributions use:

```
su - root
```

and enter your password, then :

```
echo 'YOURUSERNAME ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
```

to add the user in sudoers file.

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_OpenStack_Platform/2/html/Getting_Started_Guide/ch02s03.html

Answer (score 1):

**In order to grant to user sudo permission in shell script** (Unix/Linux) use the **usermod function**:

```
sudo usermod -aG sudo <userName>
```

**example:**

```
sudo usermod -aG sudo johnDoe
```

**For Verification:** use the **groups function** ( which show the group membership ) and verify the sudo group us under the right user.

```
groups <userName>
```

**example:**

```
groups johnDoe
#!johnDoe: johnDoe sudo
```

Explanation from [linux documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod):

> The usermod command modifies the system account files to reflect the changes that are specified on the command line.
>
> **-a, --append**
>
> Add the user to the supplementary group(s). Use only with the -G option.
>
> **-G, --groups** GROUP1[,GROUP2,...[,GROUPN]]]
>
> A list of supplementary groups which the user is also a member of. Each group is ?> separated
> from the next by a comma, with no intervening whitespace. The groups
> are subject to the same restrictions as the group given with the -g
> option. If the user is currently a member of a group which is not
> listed, the user will be removed from the group. This behaviour can be
> changed via the -a option, which appends the user to the current
> supplementary group list.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers such as spawning a subshell will work, but may not work if you want to use environmental vars. One alternative I found played really nicely for me:

```
echo "%<user>      ALL=(ALL) ALL" | sudo tee -a /etc/sudoers > /dev/null
```

This being said, hindsight is 20/20... If modifying sudoers via a script and not via visudo I would seriously recommend creating a backup with the right file permissions and contents first since you can lose access to any sudo rights without pkexec, physical access or a reboot etc.

```
sudo cp /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.bak
```

Answer (score 0):

Single line to create user with password and in sudo group.

useradd -p $(openssl passwd -1 **PASSWORD**) **USERNAME** -s /bin/bash -G sudo

Answer (score 0):

In Debian and Ubuntu you can add users to the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory. The directory has a README file. Create a file called `99_sudo_include_file` and drop it in the `/etc/sudoers.d/` directory. It's easy to remove users or add users, just create a new file and overwrite the old file. You can simply echo your new file and overwrite the old file each time you want to change it.

```
echo '#== Visudo Users - All Permissions
#== ==============================
usersam      ALL=(ALL) ALL
userlam      ALL=(ALL) ALL
userfam      ALL=(ALL) ALL

#== Visudo Users - Certain Scripts
#== ==============================
userkam      ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/script.sh, /path/to/script2.sh
useroam      ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/script.sh, /path/to/script2.sh
userpam      ALL=NOPASSWD: /path/to/script.sh, /path/to/script2.sh

#== Visudo Users - Certain Commands
#== ===============================
userpam      ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot, /usr/bin/apt-get
userwam      ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/reboot, /usr/bin/apt-get' > /etc/sudoers.d/99_sudo_include_file
```

This way you don't touch your original `/etc/sudoers` file

Answer (score -1):

Login as root to your machine. The root user are the only one who has privilege to add new user.

Once you logged-in, you may now try the following commands below:

1. Create a new user.

   adduser [username]
2. Add password to user

   passwd [username]
3. Grant root privileges to user
   Edit the visudo file by simply typing

   enter code here

Find the following line of code:
root ALL=(ALL) ALL

Then add this code below:

```
[username] ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

The original post will find on this link [Centos 6 – Creating sudoers user](http://unlimitedwebworks.guru/web/centos-6-creating-sudoers-user)

Answer (score -1):

I want continue about add user to sudoers.
I already create, but the problem is when I run twice the shell script it will add again.

## Please see below my script

```
for i in $(cat users); do

useradd $i

chsh $i /usr/bin/ksh93

echo "user $i added successfully!"

echo $i 'ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /HAapps/sudoers

echo $i:$i"123" | chpasswd

echo "Password for user $i changed successfully"

done
```

=============

### this is the result

```
ario1 ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: ALL
ario2 ALL=(ALL)    NOPASSWD: ALL
```

How to check or verify if the user already exist, so don't need add again ?
Thank you All Master
Need your advice