# Adding www-data to sudoers?

Tags: apache

I need to add www-data to sudoers, and have it to be able to execute any command without a password. I know the security risks, but for this it is needed. I am running Debian.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I edit /etc/sudoers from a script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323957/how-do-i-edit-etc-sudoers-from-a-script)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this **www-data ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL**

Comment: It is not safe to do but it is a correct answer to the question.