# How to write to /etc/sudoers file from a script without password prompt?

Tags: linux, passwords, root, edit, sudoers

I am trying to do exactly what the title of this question asks.

I have thoroughly seen [stackoverflow question #323957](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323957/how-do-i-edit-etc-sudoers-from-a-script) which is related to my question.

... and I have tried many of the solutions from the answers that were given, and they work great... **however, I am trying to do this without a password prompt**. Is there a way to pass over my password? Thanks!

Comment: So, you want to add a line to `sudoers` without giving credentials? That would be quite the security risk. An option would be to store the password and use something like `expect`, but that, again, is a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `-S` option to `sudo` which reads password from `stdin`. Something like this should do the trick:

`echo your-password | sudo -S visudo`

Comment: where does the command go? sorry ive been hidden in the Windows world forever... :/ ... or can that go at the top of a bash/shell script following my root commands?

Comment: hellllllloooooooo?

Comment: You can use it directly (shell) or in a shell script.